# Move servo incrementally within keypress loop

Tags: python, servo

After a week of searching...

I have built a robotic arm run by a Pi 3. It has 5 servos, as well as a stepper motor. I have code written see, ([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/A0igsbZK)). And I am not able to get each servo motor to move incrementally when the key press function is called. I can make the servos move to positions, but not move in between whenever I press the button.

Ideally the code would call a servo up function, and the servo would move up by increments of 20 every time the function is called.

This is the main focus:

```
def shoulder_up():
    for spwm in range(1000, 2000, 20):
        pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(shoulderpin, spwm)
        time.sleep(0.4)
        pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(shoulderpin, 0)
```

When this is called, I need the servo to move a small increment to the left. This means closer to a 1000 pwm signal value. I cannot determine how to make it move the increment every time based on the previous movement. The code currently just moves the servo through the defined range.

---

Update:

I would like to try to use this, but I cannot get the variables to change.

```
def shoulder_up():
global spwm
global nspwm
spwm = nspwm
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(shoulderpin, spwm)
nspwm = spwm + 20
```

Every time the loop runs, I want spwm to change and become 20 higher. For some reason I cant get it to change. It goes to 1520 every time.

---

Any help on this would be appreciated. Yes my code is in alpha, so it is messy and a little nonuniform.

Comment: You seriously want us to review over 200 lines of your code? Could you try to isolate the problem to a smaller section of code please?

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did more testing, and here is my final code. I determined that I was failing to reference a global variable properly. I have included the final code for those who are in the same boat. [PasteBin Robotic Arm](https://pastebin.com/t5PZt5QJ)
Thank you to those who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to define some persistent servo position variables, and then increment/decrement them (be sure to clamp the positions to limits when inc/dec)

for example something like:

```
servo_positions=[0,0,0,0,0]

def clamp(n, minn, maxn):
    return max(min(maxn, n), minn)

def inc_servo(nServo):  #nServo 0-4
    global servo_positions
    newPos = servo_positions[nServo]+10
    servo_positions[nServo] = clamp(newPos, -90, +90)
```

now in your key_loop, when '+1' pressed use inc_servo[1]

Comment: I am trying to follow what you have done. What variables do I need to change to reflect my setup?

Comment: I have tried to implement but to no avail. Here is what I have done. [https://pastebin.com/0hG9j2Xb]